# Bind Html tags without HtmlHelper in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a  ***RICH TEXT EDITOR*** with simple html , without using a custom html helper.

so it is just a simple div.

as we now

> The HtmlHelper class renders HTML controls in the razor view. It binds the model object to HTML controls to display the value of model properties into those controls and also assigns the value of the controls to the model properties while submitting a web form.

so i need the same functionality , how to bind what i m writing in the div to it's model property  ?

Comment: Well a div isn't a form field in HTML so it can't be used for 2-way binding - i.e. you can put data into it, but it won't be sent back to the server again when the form is submitted. Rich editors (like CKEditor, for example) often solve this by having a hidden textarea or hidden field in the background to which the data is copied when the form is ready to be submitted. This hidden field would have a `name` attribute matching the model object it should be bound to (which is what html.EditorFor does for regular form fields)

Comment: This isn't clear at all. You can read the source code and see how various helpers like `InputFor(model => model.Name)` work

Comment: it is not just an input , the are  buttons that have to apply some changes to it , like bold ,underline...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ADyson is write , this is what we have done :
we created a button submit which trigger a Javascript function onclick,
that Js function takes the content of the rich text editor and with Jquery it selects and changes the value of a hidden input form field before applying submit:

```
 function getTextEditor() {
            let text = $('#RichText').html().toString().trim();
            $('#DisclaimerDescription').val(text);

            $('form').submit();
        }


 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DisclaimerDescription)
```